# jQuery- Minimum Browser memory requirements

Tags: jquery, ajax, memory

We're using jQuery version 1.6 for an AJAX-based web app. I'm researching for the minimum memory  required by different browsers (primarily IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari) to render jQuery powered pages. I tried to search on Google and even docs.jquery.com but couldn't find any answer. Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ridhima

Answer (score 1):

The memory consumption by Jquery itself is not a big a problem. You have just to create a code which doesn't implies a big amount of processing, and there's nothing to fear.

I have built websites using a lot of Jquery which run smoothly even in "old" android phones.

---

A tip:

One of the things you should **avoid**, is assigning events to big number of elements. I worked in a project which I had a really big list of elements(more than 500) in a table, and I assigned click functions using something like this:

```
$('.trClass').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.someButtonClass:first').click(...)
});
```

Have always in mind, what your code really does inside it's libraries functions.
In that snippet, I was "foreaching" each one of my 500 TRs elements, and in each loop, searching for some button class and assigning it an event. The page was taken more than 5 seconds (frozen) to render completely.

I solved this problem adding an "onClick=Javascript:functionName()" manually(in "compile time") on each of the clickable elements.

Comment: +1. The HTML DOM is in and of itself ridiculously complex, adding jQuery on it is unlikely to make a difference.

Comment: In any case it is good practice to avoid assigning things to many elements. In Marcelo de Assis' example, one can instead bind a click event handler to the entire table, which will track the source element of the event and act upon it.

Comment: Marcelo,
Thanks for your inputs. But, I'm not looking for good programming tips. Assume that a customer who's not a programmer is asking this question, he wants to know how much RAM is required view web page with jQuery

Comment: Yeah, my answer to your question is before the line, the tip is only for other people who may come here and find that information valuable. As you may know, JavaScript exists for some years and runs in any possible machine, if doens't have any crazy code.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery itself isn't a huge memory hog.  I've got an old 2.2 GHz P4 machine with 1 GB of RAM and jQuery sites run just fine.

Comment: I just checked jQuery site, the latest 1.6 version is just 31KB in size. How about machines with as low as 256 MB RAM?

Comment: If you have that little ram on a desktop PC how jQuery performs will be the least of your problems.